# How to make VBA Command button search for provided input and change status if exists?

Tags: excel, vba

Ok so here is my VBA:

```
Private Sub In_Click()

Range("E2").Find.Text = TextBox1.Text And TextBox2.Text
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
RowNumber = ActiveCell.Row
Range("E(RowNumber)") = ("IN")

End Sub
```

What I am trying to make happen is, the contents of form TextBox1 and 2 are searched for and, if found, a cell in column E of whatever row the text was found (Will be the same row for both) in will be overwritten to read "IN" and the form cleared for the next entry.

If down voting or flagging in some way please tell me why at least. I cant do better if I dont know the problem.

New:

```
    Private Sub CheckIn_Click()

Dim FoundRange As Range
Dim Status As Range
    Set FoundRange = Columns("D").Find(What:=TextBox2.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
       Set Status = Columns("E")
       Status.Value = "IN"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this question as "too broad", because you haven't included any code and haven't specified any problem. If you're looking for someone to create this GUI for you, this isn't the correct place for it. If you have any existing code, please edit your post and include it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Ill get on fixing what you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use either the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) to find the first occurrence …

```
Sub In_Click()
    Dim FoundRange As Range
    Set FoundRange = Columns("E").Find(What:=TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        FoundRange.Value = "IN"
    Else
        MsgBox "not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Or the [Range.Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) to replace all occurences …

```
Sub In_Replace()
    Columns("E").Replace What:=TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text, Replacement:="IN", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

Note that if you concatenate 2 strings you must use the `&` and you cannot use the word `And`: `ConcatString = TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text`.

Comment: I seriously love members like you (there are too little), you're the only reason I have not written this site off as code snobs. You gave me real actionable help I can understand. You didn't talk over my head, ridicule me for what I failed at and or down vote without saying anything constructive. I wish there were more, this assistance could legitimately be an important factor in the present progression of my career. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Thank you again. Not to get greedy with your help but I have another issue I am struggling with here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639680/why-is-excel-vba-not-continuing-and-formatting-cell-text-and-color-etc?noredirect=1#comment96075302_54639680 If you have a chance, any input to push me in the direction I am working towards will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am running into an issue. I tweaked the code as needed but now it enters "IN' in the entire E column. Ill update the OP with what I have.

Comment: Also, every entry in the form overwrites the same cells in row 2, why is it not continuing down the form?

Comment: @Red Note that you `Set Status = Columns("E")` the entire column E here so of course the entire column gets `IN`. You must thake the `FoundRange` and then move from there into column E by `Set Status = FoundRange.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)`.